# what does attachment=True do odoo 13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I created a custom module in which I have this field

```
record_file = fields.Binary(string='file', attachment=True, help='Upload the file')
```

from what I understand `attachment=True` should save my images or pdfs to ir.attachment but am not seeing any there

am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing something wrong, `ir.attachment` records are hidden when the value of `res_field` (a Char field) is set.

When you upload the file and save, an attachment is created and the value of the `res_field` is set to `record_file` which makes it invisible under `Attachments`.

You can check that the methods [_search](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py#L403) and [read_group](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py#L387) was overridden to add `res_field=False` in the domain if not present.

Note that the default value for the `attachment` parameter is `True` so you do not need to use`attachment=True`.

***Edit:***

From [Binary](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#odoo.fields.Binary) field documentation:

> **attachment** (bool) – whether the field should be stored as ir_attachment or in a column of the model’s table (`default: True`).

Comment: Hi @Kenly I was creating a controller to gets information from module and wonted to display the pdf or image on the website how to get the url 
I was able to download `return http.send_file(maybefiel, filename='sdsdds', as_attachment=False)` it using this but I wonted to display it

Comment: I think you should ask another question, this requirement has nothing to do with the question title.

Comment: I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62908614/how-to-display-binary-field-data-in-website-using-a-controller-odoo-13 for the second part

Comment: I wonted to confirm this I used  
 ```FileStorage = kw['record_file']
     FileData = FileStorage.read()
     file_base64 = base64.encodestring(FileData)```
 to save the file from the form as it gave me this error ```TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'FileStorage'``` does this change the way it is stored in any way

Comment: also if i needed to see the file for some reason  I need to use `res_field = True`

Comment: It is a char field, its value can be the field name. You can use `Ressource Field contains "record_file"` filter to show the attachments.