# how to display binary field data in website using a controller odoo 13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-website

I was creating a controller to gets information from custom module and wonted to display the pdf or image on the website how to get the url.
I was able to download it using this

`return http.send_file(maybefiel, filename='sdsdds', as_attachment=False)`

but I wonted to display it can you please help

Answer (score 2):

You can access a binary field using the following path:

```
your_url/web/content/model_name/id/field_name
```

For example, the field name of a user's profile picture is called "**image**", so, the URL looks like something like this:

```
http://localhost:8069/web/content/res.users/1/image
```

Where **1** is the user id.

Comment: Thank you for taking  the time to answer my question, and welcome to Stack Overflow I will try it.
sorry had a odoo docker problem and trying to fix it.

Comment: This is working in backend view but not for a portal user.