# How to get all records from ir.attachment with search in Odoo 13?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

According to this answer: [what does attachment=True do odoo 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905093/what-does-attachment-true-do-odoo-13)

When you do `self.env['ir.attachment'].search([])` you do not get the records whose `res_field` is set, which commonly are the most part of the table, by the way.

Of course, I need to get records that do have the `res_id` field set. Is there a hack to do it through the `ORM` search?

Or do I have to do a SQL query instead? I guess many of you needed to do this once. Any good idea to respect ORM?

Answer (score 1):

Odoo will add [res_field=False](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py#L405) in the domain if not present (It will check if `id` or `res_field` fields are present in the domain before altering the search domain), so if you provide `id` or `res_field` Odoo will not force you to search records with `res_field` set to `False`.

The following domain should return all records in `ir.attachment`:

```
['|', ('res_field', '!=', False), ('res_field', '=',False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to respect ORM, you will custom search method.

I was customed search method once, you can try

```
from odoo.osv import expression
    class Test():
        def search(records, domain, *args, **kwargs):
            return search.origin(records, expression.AND([[('id', '=', instance.id)], domain]), *args, **kwargs)
        self.registry['odoo.instance']._patch_method('search', search)
```

If you try to fail, you have to do a SQL query

Sorry,i don't learn English very well. I'm trying learn it.